# This scope and grouping functions in nested object

Tags: javascript

I want to group similar functions in an object.
This works:

```
const dot = {
  x: 0,
  changePos() {
    this.x = random();
  }
}
```

This doesn't:

```
const dot = {
  x: 0,
  init: {
    changePos() {
      dot.x = random();
    } 
  }
}
```

In the nested version, this points to init instead of dot, so how do you go about nesting functions in an object?

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but could you write `dot.x = 200`?

Comment: You don't. Nested objects don't have a link back to the container.

Comment: @user3297291 or not, it didn't work as intended so it seems not to point at the current dot.

Comment: Can you add some example code in which it does not work as intended? It might help people suggest alternative solutions to your problem.

Comment: @user3297291 when i use random and spawn multiple dots, with this, each dot gets a unique position, but with dot.random, all dots gets same random position.
I use const newDot = Object.create(dot); newDot.init.pos() to set pos.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
I needed to bind the instance to the dot object.